# "schema_migrations" table for data mapper migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, datamapper

I am using datamapper instead of activerecord for my Rails App. I want to see the version details, but I can't see the `schema_migrations` table any where. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use explicit migrations with [dm-migrations](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-migrations#readme), it will create a `migration_info` table that contains the migration names.

```
CREATE TABLE "migration_info" ("migration_name" VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE);
```